# Multipage UserForm Excel - Add Next Button

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to add a button on page one on a Userform with multipages so that it will take you to the other pages? Can sopmeone post a simple code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Value` property of the MultiPage Control, sets/gets the active page.

---

[image]

```
 Private Sub cmdNext_Click()
        Dim lCurrentPage As Long

        lCurrentPage = Me.MultiPage1.Value + 1

        If lCurrentPage = Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count Then
            MsgBox "You are on the last page."
        Else
            Me.MultiPage1.Value = lCurrentPage
        End If

    End Sub
```